# Is there any bonus to lifting or strength for larger creature Size?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, creature-size, ability-scores

While reading about the Size classes (colossal, tiny, etc.) I noticed that they affect damage, AC, and more, but don't affect hit points or strength/lifting bonuses.

Does strength or lifting ability get modified by Size?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes, there is a bonus to lifting weight if you are larger.

The [Carrying Capacity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity/) of your character defines how much weight you can lift. It is based on your **Strength ability**, and as that increases, so does increase your *carrying capacity*.

> **Lifting and Dragging**: A character can lift as much as his maximum load over his head. A character’s maximum load is the highest amount of weight listed for a character’s Strength in the heavy load column of Table: Carrying Capacity.

Not only that, but increasing your **character's Size** also increase his carrying capacity significantly:

> **Bigger and Smaller Creatures**: The figures on Table: Carrying Capacity are for Medium bipedal creatures. A larger bipedal creature can carry more weight depending on its size category, as follows: L**arge ×2, Huge ×4, Gargantuan ×8, Colossal ×16**. A smaller creature can carry less weight depending on its size category, as follows: Small ×3/4, Tiny ×1/2, Diminutive ×1/4, Fine ×1/8.

This means that an enlarged character with 18 strength can *carry and lift twice as much weight* than a medium character with 18 strength.

Simply increasing your character's size does not automatically grant any bonus to his strength ability, as shown on the [Creature's Size](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/space-reach-threatened-area-templates#TOC-Creature-Sizes) table. But most magical effects and abilities will also grant a small bonus to your strength and constitution, like [Enlarge Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person) or [Beast Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape/).

Answer (score 1):

Not automatically, but most ways to grow *also* include increase to Strength. For example, *enlarge person* includes a Strength bonus as well as a size increase. The rules for advancing monsters to make them more dangerous include rules for increasing their size; when the GM uses those rules, the creature’s Strength also increases.

But there is no default rule that automatically increases Strength with size. You have to consult whatever effect is increasing your size. It will probably also tell you to increase Strength in some way. (It will probably also decrease Dexterity; all of the above do.)

Comment: As the question also asks about "lifting" it might be worth pointing out the rules on carrying capacity, which do increase automatically based on size: http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity/